# primereact, How to show all rows in pagination

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Actually I am trying to show all rows in my PrimeReact Datatable components, however I cannot find how to show all rows.

```
 <Table
    value={_data}
    sortMode="multiple"
    responsiveLayout="scroll"
    paginator
    rows={'All'}
  />
```

When I hit rows to all, it doesn't show all rows. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set to `rows={100000000}` some gigantic number?